# soap service zf2 return invalid xml

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, zend-framework2, response

I've created a Soap Web Service in zend framework 2, this WS works as a module that in theory works fine but my client can't read or get the response.

This is the response, i'm not sure if this response is ok, i mean why is showing this way?.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://evaluaciones.dev.com/soporte?wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getCountUserByNameResponse><return xsi:type="xsd:int">687</return></ns1:getCountUserByNameResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is a WS response that works fine.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tid.pruebas.com/webservice-soporte-portal" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:getCountUserByNameResponse>
     <return xsi:type="xsd:int">1290</return>
  </ns1:getCountUserByNameResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

at this point, i just wanna know if this situation can affect the response interpretation in the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of both responses is exactly the same, the first is just not formatted. PHP usually doesn't care about line breaks and white space when creating an XML and it never cares about it when reading one.

So, no, unformatted XMLs will never affect the clients interpretation.

Comment: I see, the problem must be the client, i assumed that the zfw version could make a difference, the client (2.0.3) is in a previous version than the WS(2.3.9).

Comment: Well, from this post to this days, i get this problem again in this case i take the whole module to other zf proyect and the web service actually works but in the original not, i can't find the problem, someone can help me?